# CSS3 text rotate

Tags: html, css

How do I acheive the following using CSS3 text-rotate

I am looking at using 2 floated elements (one just with the text and other for right panel) with a container..

[image]

Any workaround to make it work in IE8 would also be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

write like this

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

& for IE you can use filter for this

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/w7vZd/12/

& for IE8 you can conditional comment or IE css hacks.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted it...but your answer looks fine...My only question is how do I fit this into a 2-col layout like I have showin in the diagram..

Comment: Thx for the updated answer...In my case the 1st col (My Classes text) is taking up a lot of horiontal space..I mean if I give less width like say 30px, the text comes as 2-lines and not as single-line...Also I cannot increase that width by much...

Comment: filter is working you have to play with the margin which already explain 'for IE8 you can conditional comment or IE css hacks.'

Comment: So even in your example, if I play with the margins, I should see in IE8 (as of now, I can't in http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/w7vZd/12/ )

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
-webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
transform:rotate(-90deg);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

on the element. (Might be 90, not -90 – you'll have to check!). The IE one just takes values of 1,2,3,4 representing each 90˚ rotation.